# Setting a theme-dependent css source that overrides all others

Tags: xpages

My scenario is the following:

I have an XPages application to which I have added two themes - call them 'red' and 'blue'. The same template is deployed on two different servers, a 'red' and a 'blue' server. There are some css definitions already defined in the custom control and I want to add a last one (an overriding one) to the custom control:

```
    <xp:styleSheet href="/custom.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/bootstrap.min.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/docs.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    <xp:styleSheet href="TRYING TO GET VALUE FROM THEME "   ></xp:styleSheet>
```

I've added the following control to both themes:

```
<control>
    <name>ThemeSpecificCss</name>
    <property>
        <name>value</name>
        <value>red.css</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

and what I was trying to do was

```
<xp:styleSheet themeId="ThemeSpecificCSS"></xp:styleSheet>
```

but that's not working.

I'm not including the css file as a resource like this:

```
    <resource> <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>mystylesheet.css</href> </resource>
```

because the custom control csses would override it.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question simply you can use SSJS:

```
var themeName = context.getSessionProperty("xsp.theme");
```

or using Java:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
XSPContext context = (XSPContext) facesContext.getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(facesContext, "context");
String themeName = context.getSessionProperty("xsp.theme");
```

That will give you the name of the theme. However you may want to re-think your theme structure. You can define theme specific css resources in the themes. This would allow you to have different css files depending on the theme selected. Since themes can inherit from other themes you should be able to build a dependency structure that would accomplish your goal. For example:

- baseTheme (contains css and properties that all the themes need)
- red-theme (extends baseTheme)
- red-ccTheme (extends red-theme)
- blue-theme (extends baseTheme)
- blue-ccTheme (extends blue-theme)

For a great example of theme inheritance take a look at [Tim Tripcony's HowyaBean project](https://bitbucket.org/timtripcony/howyabean/src/9d5b865c752195e6b8b9d6f88930745b4ba229a4/howyabean%20ODP/Resources/Themes/?at=default) for inspiration.

Comment: Keith, that's really cool. The issue I have is that the theme  css files get loaded before the css files on the Xpage, thus getting overidden.

Comment: That's why you should add them all to a theme. If you need styling for a specific element then I would do it via a style block (<style></style>) instead of a resource assignment.

Comment: That's genius, should have thought of that. Just push all the styling into the themes. Brilliant! Solves my problem very elegantly. Many cheers!